# Cryptic stacktrace crashing in objc_object::release()

Tags: objective-c, memory, crash, core-image

I'm analyzing the following stack traces in Crashlytics. I'm unable to reproduce the issue on my phones. Below are the crashed thread. The stack traces are slightly different between 64 and 32 bit CPUs.

The only interesting piece of information is that there is another thread resizing an image in the background (there is no UI manipulation involved).

Since resizing the image could put some pressure on the phone's memory, I suspect this is a memory-related error, but I wouldn't expect to see a stack trace in that case and I also don't see any memory warning in the logs. Does that make sense? Or should I look for something completely different? Any suggestion would be helpful.

Would you have any suggestion about what could be happening there?

**On iPhone 5S, iPad Air, the crash thread is as follow:**

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00000001e256bec8

Thread : Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x000000018f65a984 objc_object::release() + 8
1  libsystem_blocks.dylib         0x000000018fc5f908 _Block_release + 256
2  libdispatch.dylib              0x000000018fc17fd4 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
3  libdispatch.dylib              0x000000018fc1b1dc _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 336
4  CoreFoundation                 0x00000001830f6ddc __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12
5  CoreFoundation                 0x00000001830f511c __CFRunLoopRun + 1452
6  CoreFoundation                 0x0000000183035dd0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 452
7  GraphicsServices               0x0000000188d1dc0c GSEventRunModal + 168
```

While executing in a high priority thread:

```
Thread : com.apple.root.high-priority
0  CoreGraphics                   0x00000001831cef88 resample_byte_h_4cpp_armv7 + 420
1  CoreGraphics                   0x00000001831cec74 resample_band + 1188
2  CoreGraphics                   0x00000001831cd9b0 img_interpolate_read + 816
3  CoreGraphics                   0x00000001831c94cc img_data_lock + 4440
4  CoreGraphics                   0x00000001831c7944 CGSImageDataLock + 148
5  libRIP.A.dylib                 0x0000000183573dec ripc_AcquireImage + 160
6  libRIP.A.dylib                 0x0000000183573460 ripc_DrawImage + 624
7  CoreGraphics                   0x00000001831c7674 CGContextDrawImage + 408
8  My App                         0x00000001005105a4 -[UIImage(Async) scaleWithMaxSize:quality:scale:] (UIImage+Async.m:50)
9  My App                         0x0000000100144244 __38-[ViewController viewDidAppear:]_block_invoke (ViewController.m:79)
10 libdispatch.dylib              0x000000018fc18014 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
11 libdispatch.dylib              0x000000018fc17fd4 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
12 libdispatch.dylib              0x000000018fc1f2b8 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 556
13 libdispatch.dylib              0x000000018fc1f4fc _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 76
14 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x000000018fdad6bc _pthread_wqthread + 356
```

**On iPhone 5, 4S, 4, it's slightly different**

```
Crashed: com.apple.root.default-priority
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x2146c7cf

Thread : Crashed: com.apple.root.default-priority
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x382af66a objc_release + 9
1  libsystem_blocks.dylib         0x387caac5 _Block_release + 216
2  libsystem_blocks.dylib         0x387caac5 _Block_release + 216
3  libxpc.dylib                   0x388d9e71 _xpc_connection_call_reply + 32
4  libdispatch.dylib              0x3878fad7 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 222
5  libdispatch.dylib              0x3878fd29 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 56
6  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x388cabd3 _pthread_wqthread + 298
```

also while executing in a high priority thread:

```
Thread : com.apple.root.high-priority
0  CoreGraphics                   0x2d6749e6 resample_byte_h_4cpp_armv7 + 117
1  ???                            0x00000002 
2  CoreGraphics                   0x2d67487d resample_band + 884
3  CoreGraphics                   0x2d673a47 img_interpolate_read + 562
4  CoreGraphics                   0x2d6701d3 img_data_lock + 4514
5  CoreGraphics                   0x2d66e82d CGSImageDataLock + 88
6  libRIP.A.dylib                 0x2d9bae67 ripc_AcquireImage + 98
7  libRIP.A.dylib                 0x2d9ba20d ripc_DrawImage + 588
8  CoreGraphics                   0x2d66e743 CGContextDelegateDrawImage + 50
9  CoreGraphics                   0x2d66e5d9 CGContextDrawImage + 284
10 My App                         0x0050f469 -[UIImage(Async) scaleWithMaxSize:quality:scale:] (UIImage+Async.m:50)
11 My App                         0x00153fc7 __38-[ViewController viewDidAppear:]_block_invoke (ViewController.m:79)
12 libdispatch.dylib              0x38788833 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 10
13 libdispatch.dylib              0x3878fad7 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 222
14 libdispatch.dylib              0x3878fd29 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 56
15 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x388cabd3 _pthread_wqthread + 298
```

Comment: I would suspect that something has been over-released.

Comment: Is there a correlation with what's happening in the high priority thread?

Comment: I'm going to agree with Hot Licks and say that looks like async blocks being passed around resulting in releasing an object that's already been released. I had one with sounds that I couldn't reproduce, until I started memory maxing the device to get the threads to time up badly like was happening in the wild.

Comment: I see. You're saying that the slow operation might just delay enough some thread that some object is released before it's accessed. I could try adding some NSThread sleep in my background operations.

Comment: @Kamchatka Did you ever figure it out? I am running into the exact same issue, and would love to hear what you found out